# Substitute some values from a field into another

Tags: pandas

I'd like to substitute some valors from a field into another. For instance:
Let's say I have a **pandas.DataFrame** object with an identifier **df** (yeap, very original), it has several columns but there are some of them which are relevant, and cannot be empty.

I noticed some of the values were set into another field. Let's say **field1** is a relevant field, and **field2** is not. I have a thousand of registers and it's increasing every week, when I get new data, and as I love make things be automated I first check for these possible values:

```
idx = df[df.field1.isna() & df.field2.notna()].index
```

Then I tried to replace them:

```
df.loc[idx, ['field1']] = df.loc[idx, ['field2']]
```

But when I see the result nothing has changed... why? I con make substitutions this way with a single value, but if they differ I cannot anymore.

```
df.loc[idx, ['field1']] = "Not empty any longer"  # This will work
```

I can't figure it out how to achieve this in a ... good way? I mean, I don't want to check it manually, it doesn't matter if they're only 50, I have to do the same with other fields and I may get more like this (and I will).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this: `df.loc[idx, ['field1']] = df.loc[idx, ['field2']].values`

Example:

```
# The None in 'field1' should be replaced by the 'field2' value
df = pd.DataFrame({'field1':[1,2,3,None,5], 'field2':[6,7,8,8,None]})
idx = df[df.field1.isna() & df.field2.notna()].index
df.loc[idx, ['field1']] = df.loc[idx, ['field2']].values
```

Original dataframe:

```
df
   field1  field2
0     1.0     6.0
1     2.0     7.0
2     3.0     8.0
3     NaN     8.0
4     5.0     NaN
```

Modified df:

```
df
   field1  field2
0     1.0     6.0
1     2.0     7.0
2     3.0     8.0
3     8.0     8.0
4     5.0     NaN
```

Comment: Thank you Derek O, this is just what I was looking for ;-). It solved my problem.